# Having a hard time getting Javascript to work in a post

Tags: posts, javascript

I'm trying to get [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/33cEe/19/) to work on the test post. The goal is to have the links below the video jump to certain spots in the video. It works fine in the jsfiddle demo, but not on my post.

In my header.php, I load that script and the script it refers to:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://wcportal.acbaldwin.info/js/vimeochapters.js"></script>
</head>
```

In the post that I want to use, I inserted this markup in text-only view:

```
<iframe width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569?api=1&amp;player_id=player_1" id="player_1">
</iframe>
<h2>Chapters</h2>
<ul class="chapterLinks">
<li><a class="seek" href="#" name="15">Seek to 15</a></li>
<li><a class="seek" href="#" name="30">Seek to 30</a></li>
<li><a class="seek" href="#" name="60">Seek to 60</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Here's the test page](http://wcportal.acbaldwin.info/2013/05/02/hd-test-3-chapters/)

I'm sure I'm calling something incorrectly, but I don't know where. I'm not sure I saved the .js file correctly or if there need to be additional tags within the .js file.
I know there are more optimized and wordpress friendly ways to integrate JS, but I just need quick, dirty, and functioning for a demo.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you right click and select Inspect Element on Chrome or Safari or have Firebug in Firefox, it will tell you in the console, what your errors are.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution here from a redditor:
http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1dn0j6/im_having_a_hard_time_getting_javascript_to_work/c9rwy85

Turns out the script needed to be in the footer. (Either that or I had a lucky coincidence while fixing an ajax issue!)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing an ending } on the vimeofunction(); in the vimeochapters.js file.